# how to get itemid when we dynamically add menu in navigationdrawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-menu

I am adding menu for navigation drawer dynamically like this :

```
 for(int i = 0;i<UtilInsta.MenuList.size();i++)
        {
            switch (UtilInsta.MenuList.get(i).BANNER_CODE)
            {
                case "AF" :
                    menu.add(UtilInsta.MenuList.get(i).BANNER_DESC).setIcon(R.drawable.application_form);
                    break;
                case "PD" :
                    menu.add(UtilInsta.MenuList.get(i).BANNER_DESC).setIcon(R.drawable.pending_doc);
                    break;
                case "VD" :
                    menu.add(UtilInsta.MenuList.get(i).BANNER_DESC).setIcon(R.drawable.view_doc_nav);
                    break;
                case "PF" :
                    menu.add(UtilInsta.MenuList.get(i).BANNER_DESC).setIcon(R.drawable.pay_free);
                    break;
                case "RD" :
                    menu.add(UtilInsta.MenuList.get(i).BANNER_DESC).setIcon(R.drawable.refree_detail);
                    break;
                case "IC" :
                    menu.add(UtilInsta.MenuList.get(i).BANNER_DESC).setIcon(R.drawable.information);
                    break;
                case "CP" :
                    menu.add(UtilInsta.MenuList.get(i).BANNER_DESC).setIcon(R.drawable.change_pass);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

and  when the item is selected and when onNavigationItemSelected is called the item.getitemid() only gives 0 as return,

so how do i know which item is selected?

Comment: Isn't it item.getItemId(); ?http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#getItemId()

Answer (score 0):

Are you implementing something like:

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}
```

It should give you all the information you need, no?

Comment: i donot have a listview, i have added menu to navigation drawer

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but check out the [Navigation Drawer Reference](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). `DrawerLayout` is in the support.v4 Package, there's no real Reason not to use it.